# Array of dictionaries to Jinja2 from flask is unexpectedly transformed to a string

Tags: vue.js, flask, jinja2

I have a flask app, with one route:

```
cameras = [
    { 'id': 1, 'format': 'png' }
]

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', cameras=cameras)
```

And in my jinja2 template, I call a Vue component with each of the cameras:

```
{% for camera in cameras %}
    <camera-viewer camera_info={{ camera }}></camera-viewer>
{% endfor %}
```

And Vue is expecting camera_info to be an Object, but it's being received as a string and gives the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "camera_info". Expected Object, got String with value "{'id':"
```

Because I have specified the `camera_info` prop to be of type `Object`.

So it looks like Jinja is not recognizing that camera is a dictionary? I have tried using filters `tojson`, `fromjson`, `to_dict` but none of them seem to be available in jinja2. https://tedboy.github.io/jinja2/templ14.html

Only possible workaround I can think of is to pass the object as a string to Vue and then deal with it in there, but that's more of a hack than a solution.

Comment: The error means what it says, camera_info is a string. Check vue syntax for props. Should be `:camera_info="{{ camera }}"` instead of `camera_info={{ camera }}`. Also notice that {{ }} delimiters are in conflict

Comment: @EstusFlask as for the delimiters, I have changed the ones of Vue to [%[ ]%]. I have already tried (and did again now just in case), but even with the `"{{ camera }}"` I have the same issue.

Comment: It's a colon that matters. See https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#prop-passing-details

Comment: ooof, not sure how I missed that... guess I mistakenly thought it was prerendered and binding not necessary.

Comment: @EstusFlask if you want to add an answer I'll mark it as solved. But maybe it's better to just remove the question, since it will be misleading when googling.

Comment: I'd suggest to keep it as a dupe, this has already been answered and increases the visibility of the problem